# How can I do something as soon as a collapse item is closed?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, bootstrap-5

In the Bootstrap 5 documentation it says: You can create a collapse instance with the constructor, for example:

```
var myCollapse = document.getElementById('myCollapse')
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: false
})
```

I need to close it on the click of a certain element and so I did so

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", el => {
  if (el.target.matches("#send-search")) {
    el.preventDefault();

    // Closing element
    new bootstrap.Collapse(document.querySelector("#find-el"), {
      hide: true,
    });

    // Do stuff do stuff when it is completely closed

  }
});
```

the element closes...

what I need is to perform a certain operation but only when the element is completely closed

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#events

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener for the `hidden.bs.collapse` event...

```
myCollapse.addEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('closed!')
})
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/uSKVzr7uYT

Comment: in my example the closure is inside a listener, if I add what is recommended it tells me: Uncaught TypeError: bsCollapse.addEventListener is not a function.

clearly I have attributed the variable bsCollapse to the object

if I put everything outside the click function it works but inside it doesn't

@Zim

Comment: Ya, the approach you're using isn't typical. Why are you re-instantiating the bootstrap.Collapse inside the listener? Also, why is the click event listener on the entire body? Can you show more of the relevant code and how the Collapse is opened/shown?

Comment: I have re-instantiating because I have not found another way to close it, if there was another way I would be happy to use it.

I attack the click on the body because I use delegate the listener for elements added on the DOM at a later time @Zim

Comment: So how is the collapse initially opened? Note: the addEventListener should be on the collapse element, not the Bootstrap Collapse instance. I updated the answer

Comment: it works like this: I have a button that calls the opening of the form for the search, when I send the search I would like to first close the form and then call the function that performs the search, I have not instantiated anything elsewhere in Bootstrap 5 not you need to do nothing for it to work or at least it works without me having instantiated anything @Zim